# Regex to match a string-form matrix

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to match the matrix out of the string (for example) `sin([[1,2][3,4]])`, but I cannot for the life of me figure out a working regex. I've tried things like `\[[0-9\.,\[\]]*\]` but none have worked. I'm working in Java (on Android).

Can anyone help me please? This is the last thing preventing from making a big git commit.

More details: the matrices will be any size, like `[[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8][9,10,1,12]]`. I want a regex that will put out the whole matrix (not individual parts, because it'll be surrounded by things like functions, operators, etc. Numbers in the matrix will be either integer or double. Scientific notation is possible too. Hex/other bases are not.

Resolution: the reason `\[.+\]` wasn't working was because Java's String.matches didn't work the way I thought it did, and because I was using it in combination with another regex (that worked fine itself). Apparently `?|` means something in regex.

Comment: Could you give us more info on the grammar? Are pairs comma-separated? Are decimals, hex, scientific notation, etc. supported?

Comment: I want the whole matrix as it appears in the original string verbatim.

Comment: So for example you want the first matrix pulled out as `1,2,3,4`?

Comment: No, I want the first matrix pulled out as `[[1,2][3,4]]`.

Comment: Doesn't match in my java code.

Answer (score 0):

```
\[(\d+\.?\d*),(\d+\.?\d*)\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/GZ_EkqLK0i6Rj2nw)

Something like this? I'm sort of confused what you are trying to do. This code extracts the values out of a group like `[digit,digit]` and puts them into two capture groups. It also handles decimals :).

Answer (score 0):

I used the following regex to validate string for matching vector (comma separated numbers inside square brackets) or matrix (comma separated vectors inside square brackets). Handles negative and positive numbers, decimals numbers and even exponential notation numbers.

```
/(\[+([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?,?)+[\]\,]+)+/g
```

The above regex can match:

- A vector : [0.04260090287650773,0.3618834344248428]
- A matrix : [[1.00,4.00,6.10],[0.04,0.36,7.0],[5.0,0.67,0.33]]

I used to validate data in JSON format coming from a web service, to ensure that the values provided are correctly formatted as vectors or list of vectors (matrix).

It works form me, I hope to be useful for anybody.